# Network drives don't get mapped and desktop redirection stops working when domain user becomes a member of the Local Administrator group on their PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-sbs-2003, mappeddrive

We have a Small Business Server 2003 domain controller with Windows 7 workstations joined to the domain.

I noticed recently that, if I make a user a local administrator on his computer, his redirected desktop and mapped network drives do not connect at login (error on login that network drives inaccessible and desktop is blank).

However, it is still possible for this user to browse to his home directory where his redirected folders are located- so he still has access to that location.

Does anyone have any theories as to what is going on here?

Comment: Have you checked the Event Viewer? You may get a more accurate error.

Comment: Also, are you 100% sure that this is inline with being a Local Admin. I.e., is it reproducible - if you remove him from the group, does it start working again? And vice versa.

Comment: I've only tried on one workstation so far, but it is 100% reproducible. I'll check out Event Viewer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this late last year.

It turns out the previous sysadmin had left a mess in AD (lots of nested security groups). Somehow, this ended up causing unpredictable behaviour.

After reorganizing all of the AD security groups from scratch, everything started working perfectly.